# Bounded and open simply connected region is smoothly contractible.

Tags: differential-geometry, connectedness, de-rham-cohomology

Let $U\subset \Bbb R^2$ be open, bounded, and simply connected. Is it true that $U$ is smoothly contractible to a point?

By the Whitney Approximation Theorem, it suffices to find a continuous $H :U\times [0,1]\to U$ s.t. $H(x,0)=x$ and $H(x,1)=x_0\in U$. If I could assume the Riemann mapping theorem, this would be trivial. Just send $U$ to the unit disk and contract to the origin. Unfortunately, this is a question from Spivak's Differential Geometry books, and so far there has been no mention of the Riemann mapping theorem, so I believe I should not use it in the proof.

What has been covered so far is some basic de Rham cohomology, but all I know in this connection is that $H^1(M)=0$ for a simply connected manifold. I do not have any sort of converse result where the cohomology group tells me anything about the underlying space. Am I barking up the wrong tree? Is the proof along another direction?

Comment: I do not think there is a completely elementary proof of this. One argument is to observe $U$ admits a triangulation, hence, $H_i(U, {\mathbb Z})=0, i\ge 2$, then use Hurewicz to prove that that $\pi_i(U)=0, i\ge 2$, then use Whitehead to construct the homotopy $H$. Use the classification of surfaces to prove that $U$ has an exhaustion by simplicial disks and, hence, $\pi_i(U)=0, i\ge 2$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan while it is reassuring that the proof is not trivial, none of those topics have appeared so far in the book. Spivak defines simple connectedess by saying that any $f : S^1\to U$ admits a homotopy to a constant map. Is this definition more helpful?

Comment: You forgot to assume that $U$ is connected, otherwise, it is one of the several equivalent definitions of simple connectivity. No, it does not simplify anything. Maybe Spivak was assuming Riemann Mapping Theorem or simply did not think long enough when he wrote this. Such things happen.

Comment: I looked at volume 1 of Spivak's "Differential Geometry" book (where you found this problem). He simply does not give you enough tools to solve the stated problems. Just ignore this problem and move on.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you, that is what I decided on doing.